# How can you add a content block to magento onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, php-5.4

I want to add a custom text block to the magento one page check out. The block will just have text advising of no refund policy. Please let me know what exact magento file needs modification and wheres its located. Or if there's a better way to display a message during check out.

Comment: I want to add a custom block to check out page. Is this still too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default magento provide terms & conditions feature in checkout page so you dont need to write any thing in file

To enable this

1. Login in your magento
2. `System menu>Configuration>Checkout` button in the Sales section on the `left>Checkout` Options panel on the right. Expand the panel and set the drop-down menu `Enable Terms and Conditions to Yes`

Now next step is

1. `Menu > Sales > Terms and conditions`
2. `Add New Condition`
3. Fill in the required fields
4. Set “`Status`” to “`Enabled`”
5. Set “Show content as” to “HTML” if you need HTML.
6. “Checkbox text” will be shown next to the checkbox, in example: “I accept the terms and conditions”
7. “Content” will be shown in a scrolling text area above the checkbox. Depends.
8. Then “`Save Condition`”

That’s it.

Let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0):

Checkout codes can be seen in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage`. If you are using custom theme, please check in corresponding template folder.

Billing, shipping, payment method, shipping method and review html resides in this path.